DynamoDB Index Design for Finding Items Where an Attribute Contains a Specific Value
Problem
I am currently in the process of designing the database for a software application which will be used by multiple organizations to each manage multiple projects. I am planning on using DynamoDB for the database. The question I have centres around one query I need to perform on the "Projects" table. The queries I will need to perform are as follows:

Find Projects by organization_id.
Find Project by id.
Find Projects by status.
Find Projects by members.

Note: Each Project entity will have an organization_id, id, status, and array of members (user id's).
The problem I am trying to solve is with query #4. Each project can have multiple members, and when a user logs into their dashboard, I want to fetch and display only the projects which that user is a part of. The issue is that the "members" field in a project entity is an array with user id's, which means the "members" of one project could be the same as another project, meaning it won't guarantee uniqueness.
One of the indexes I will use for this table will use the organization_id as the Partition Key and the id as the Sort Key. I would like to do something similar for the index I will use for query #4, but since "members" is not unique within its partition, I cannot use it as the Sort Key.
Possible Solutions
1 - User to Project Table
This solution would require me to create an extra table. This table would relate each user id to an array of project id's. When a user loads their dashboard, I could fetch their user entry for this table and do a Batch Item request and get all the projects by their id's in the array.
Pros:

Lower overhead than a Query with Filter Expression (I think).

Cons:

Requires an entire extra table.
Added complexity to update multiple tables when a user is added/removed from a project.
Will require a batch item request to get multiple projects by id, increasing required processing.

2 - Query with Filter Expression
For this solution, I would do a Query with organization_id as the Partition Key with a Filter set to find items where "members" CONTAINS the user id I am looking for.
Pros:

No extra table needed.

Cons:

Filter expressions apply only after the base query is made, meaning the query will have the same overhead whether or not the filter is applied. For every request made to this endpoint, I will essentially be getting all projects with a specific organization_id, and then filtering over them to find the right ones (not efficient).
Following the previous point, Queries only return up to a maximum of 1MB of data. Since the filter is applied after the original Query, this means that if the total number of Projects in an organization exceeds the 1MB limit per request, I could receive nothing back from a Query after my filter expression even if there exists a matching Project in the database, meaning I would have to do another request with pagination until I find it.

3 - Other
I am hoping there exists another solution where I can perform a single request and get all the data I need. I see a Z-index as a possible solution but haven't fully figured out the best way to make use of it.
Any Help Appreciated
Does anyone have experience with a problem like this? I know this is a common data model so I imagine there must be a good way to do this, but I have not been unable to find a way that seems optimal. All comments are welcome. Thanks in advance!

Typically you'd map that like the following:



PK
SK
Data
OrgId




project123
project123
all project data
org0001


project123
user001
any specific user data for this project



project123
user002
any specific user data for this project



project123
user099
any specific user data for this project



project999
project999
all project data
org0346



Then you can create a GSI with SK as the partition key and that would give you all projects related to a user. Then you can do a BatchGetItem to obtain all the project metadata from the base table.
An alternative approach is to overload your GSI so that you only have to make one index to supply you both with all projects for a given user or org.



PK
SK
Data
GSI1PK




project123
project123
all project data
org0001


project123
user001
any specific user data for this project
user001


project123
user002
any specific user data for this project
user002


project123
user099
any specific user data for this project
user099


project999
project999
all project data
org0346



With this data model you can use GSI1PK as your index partition key. And you can supply either a userId or OrgId as partition key value depending on your lookup.

Hey, thanks for the reply! With this model, how would I maintain the ability to get all projects by organization_id? Am I basically just stuck with making a separate table at this point? I think that's where I am getting confused because I assumed project_id would make the most sense as a PK.

Edited the data model in my answer. You just create an index on OrgId and that would do the same, list all projects for a given org.

Very interesting! I did not know about overloading indexes. In the past I have never had multiple types of data in a single "column" so this is new for me. Just to confirm, your recommendation is Primary Index; (PK: ProjId, SK: ProjId/UserId), GSI #1; (PK: UserId/ProjId, SK: n/a), GSI #2; (PK: OrgId, SK: n/a). Or I can combine both GSI's into one with overloading. Does that sound right? I am also curious what naming convention you would use for these attributes that can have multiple values. Sorry for the dumb questions, I am not an expert with dynamodb.

Your understanding is correct, and not a dumb question at all. Typically in DynamoDB we give the attributes which we overload generic names. Base table would be PK/SK and indexes would be GSI1PK/GSI1SK, GSI2PK....etc.. For your use-case, I think going the route of a single index will be nice.

That makes perfect sense. I will mark this as the accepted answer. Thanks a lot for your help.
